# Google Maps V3 Styling or Markers not showing up depending on what API javascript source I am using

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map setup where I can see the markers correctly, but no styling if I use this source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/3/apiv3.js"></script>
```

and I can see my styling correctly, but no markers if I use this source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
```

I have looked through both of the source codes and I can't figure out what is causing the issue either way.  I thought it was a version issue, or that I needed to create a styledMapType, but since both work just with different sources I'm now completely lost on this.

My code is as follows *(with styled but no markers source):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> </head><body>

<!-- ++Begin GSpreadsheets Map Wizard Generated Code++ -->

<div style="width:575px; font-family:Arial, 
sans-serif; font-size:11px; border:1px solid black">
  <table id="cm_mapTABLE"> <tbody> <tr id="cm_mapTR">

    <td> <div id="cm_map" style="width:450px; height:450px"></div> </td>
  </tr> </tbody></table>
</div>

<!-- Here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
var cm_map;
var cm_openInfowindow;
var cm_mapMarkers = [];
var cm_mapHTMLS = [];

// Change these parameters to customize map
var param_wsId = "od6";
//Edited Out var param_ssKey = "";
var param_useSidebar = true;
var param_titleColumn = "name"
var param_descriptionColumn = "name";
var param_latColumn = "lat";
var param_lngColumn = "long";
var param_rankColumn = "";
var param_iconType = "green";
var param_iconOverType = "orange";

/**
 * Loads map and calls function to load in worksheet data.
 */
function cm_load() {  
  var styles = [
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "simplified" },
      { "color": "#808080" },
      { "weight": 2.9 }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#808080" },
      { "weight": 0.1 }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },
      { featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'all', stylers: [ { visibility: 'off' } ] },
      { featureType: 'transit', elementType: 'all', stylers: [ { visibility: 'off' } ] },
      { featureType: 'water', elementType: 'all', stylers: [{ color: '#6FADC3' }] },
      { featureType: 'landscape', elementType: 'all', stylers: [{ color: '#999999' }] },
      { featureType: 'administrative.province', elementType: 'all', stylers: [{visibility: "off"}] },
      { featureType: 'administrative.locality', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: "simplified"}] },
      { featureType: 'administrative.locality', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{color: "#ffffff"}] },
      { featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: "simplified"}] },
      { featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{color: "#ffffff"}] }
      ]

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741);
  var myOptions = {
    key: 'ABQIAAAA-O3c-Om9OcvXMOJXreXHAxRlOb26qSyU154aZeLwOrF4C7-DphSw7JoLuXrcDjUb_7h-S1txkSCY7A',
    zoom: 2,
    styles: styles,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    sensor: '<i>set_to_true_or_false</i>',
  }

  cm_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("cm_map"), myOptions);

  //  cm_map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  //  cm_map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  cm_getJSON();
}

/**
 * Function called when marker on the map is clicked.
 * Opens an info window (bubble) above the marker.
 * @param {Number} markerNum Number of marker in global array
 */
function cm_markerClicked(markerNum) {
  var infowindowOptions = {
    content: cm_mapHTMLS[markerNum]
  }
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      infowindowOptions,
      cm_map,
      cm_mapMarkers[markerNum]);
  cm_setInfowindow(infowindow);
}

/**
 * Function that sorts 2 worksheet rows from JSON feed
 * based on their rank column. Only called if column is defined.
 * @param {rowA} Object Represents row in JSON feed
 * @param {rowB} Object Represents row in JSON feed
 * @return {Number} Difference between row values
 */
function cm_sortRows(rowA, rowB) {
  var rowAValue = parseFloat(rowA["gsx$" + param_rankColumn].$t);
  var rowBValue = parseFloat(rowB["gsx$" + param_rankColumn].$t);

  return rowAValue - rowBValue;
}

/** 
 * Called when JSON is loaded. Creates sidebar if param_sideBar is true.
 * Sorts rows if param_rankColumn is valid column. Iterates through worksheet rows, 
 * creating marker and sidebar entries for each row.
 * @param {JSON} json Worksheet feed
 */       
function cm_loadMapJSON(json) {
  var usingRank = false;

  if(param_useSidebar == true) {
    var sidebarTD = document.createElement("td");
    sidebarTD.setAttribute("width","150");
    sidebarTD.setAttribute("valign","top");
    var sidebarDIV = document.createElement("div");
    sidebarDIV.id = "cm_sidebarDIV";
    sidebarDIV.style.overflow = "auto";
    sidebarDIV.style.height = "450px";
    sidebarDIV.style.fontSize = "11px";
    sidebarDIV.style.color = "#000000";
    sidebarTD.appendChild(sidebarDIV);
    document.getElementById("cm_mapTR").appendChild(sidebarTD);
  }

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  if(json.feed.entry[0]["gsx$" + param_rankColumn]) {
    usingRank = true;
    json.feed.entry.sort(cm_sortRows);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    if(entry["gsx$" + param_latColumn]) {
      var lat = parseFloat(entry["gsx$" + param_latColumn].$t);
      var lng = parseFloat(entry["gsx$" + param_lngColumn].$t);
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = "<div style='font-size:12px'>";
      html += "<strong>" + entry["gsx$"+param_titleColumn].$t 
              + "</strong>";
      var label = entry["gsx$"+param_titleColumn].$t;
      var rank = 0;
      if(usingRank && entry["gsx$" + param_rankColumn]) {
        rank = parseInt(entry["gsx$"+param_rankColumn].$t);
      }
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_descriptionColumn]) {
        html += "<br/>" + entry["gsx$"+param_descriptionColumn].$t;
      }
      html += "</div>";

      // create the marker
      var marker = cm_createMarker(cm_map,point,label,html,rank);
      // cm_map.addOverlay(marker);
      cm_mapMarkers.push(marker);
      cm_mapHTMLS.push(html);
      bounds.extend(point);

      if(param_useSidebar == true) {
        var markerA = document.createElement("a");
        markerA.setAttribute("href","javascript:cm_markerClicked('" + i +"')");
        markerA.style.color = "#000000";
        var sidebarText= "";
        if(usingRank) {
          sidebarText += rank + ") ";
        } 
        sidebarText += label;
        markerA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sidebarText));
        sidebarDIV.appendChild(markerA);
        sidebarDIV.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        sidebarDIV.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      } 
    }
  }

  cm_map.fitBounds(bounds);
  cm_map.set_center(bounds.getCenter());
}

function cm_setInfowindow(newInfowindow) {
  if (cm_openInfowindow != undefined) {
    cm_openInfowindow.close();
  }

  cm_openInfowindow = newInfowindow;
}

/**
 * Creates marker with ranked Icon or blank icon,
 * depending if rank is defined. Assigns onclick function.
 * @param {GLatLng} point Point to create marker at
 * @param {String} title Tooltip title to display for marker
 * @param {String} html HTML to display in InfoWindow
 * @param {Number} rank Number rank of marker, used in creating icon
 * @return {GMarker} Marker created
 */
function cm_createMarker(map, latlng, title, html, rank) {
  var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(20, 34);
  var iconShadowSize = new google.maps.Size(37, 34);
  var iconHotSpotOffset = new google.maps.Point(9, 0); // Should this be (9, 34)?
  var iconPosition = new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
  var infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(9, 2);
  var infoShadowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(18, 25);

  var iconShadowUrl = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
  var iconImageUrl;
  var iconImageOverUrl;
  var iconImageOutUrl;

  if(rank > 0 && rank < 100) {
    iconImageOutUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
        "markers/" + param_iconType + "/marker" + rank + ".png";
    iconImageOverUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
        "markers/" + param_iconOverType + "/marker" + rank + ".png";
    iconImageUrl = iconImageOutUrl;
  } else { 
    iconImageOutUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
        "markers/" + param_iconType + "/blank.png";
    iconImageOverUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
        "markers/" + param_iconOverType + "/blank.png";
    iconImageUrl = iconImageOutUrl;
  }

  var markerShadow =
      new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconShadowUrl, iconShadowSize,
                                  iconPosition, iconHotSpotOffset);

  var markerImage =
      new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconImageUrl, iconSize,
                                  iconPosition, iconHotSpotOffset);

  var markerImageOver =
      new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconImageOverUrl, iconSize,
                                  iconPosition, iconHotSpotOffset);

  var markerImageOut =
      new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconImageOutUrl, iconSize,
                                  iconPosition, iconHotSpotOffset);

  var markerOptions = {
    title: title,
    icon: markerImage,
    shadow: markerShadow
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(latlng, markerOptions, map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    var infowindowOptions = {
      content: html
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        infowindowOptions,
        map,
        marker);
    cm_setInfowindow(infowindow);
    marker.set_icon(markerImageOut);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
    marker.set_icon(markerImageOver);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
    marker.set_icon(markerImageOut);
  });

  return marker;
}

var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

/**
 * Creates a script tag in the page that loads in the 
 * JSON feed for the specified key/ID. 
 * Once loaded, it calls cm_loadMapJSON.
 */
function cm_getJSON() {

  // Retrieve the JSON feed.
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.setAttribute('src', 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list'
                         + '/' + param_ssKey + '/' + param_wsId + '/public/values' +
                        '?alt=json-in-script&callback=cm_loadMapJSON');
  script.setAttribute('id', 'jsonScript');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}

setTimeout('cm_load()', 500); 

//]]>

</script>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is partially outdated.

You must change some things

1. replace this line:

   ```
   cm_map.set_center(bounds.getCenter());
   ```

   with

   ```
   cm_map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
   ```
2. replace the function `cm_markerClicked` with:

   ```
   function cm_markerClicked(markerNum) {

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: cm_mapHTMLS[markerNum]
       });
     infowindow.open(cm_map, cm_mapMarkers[markerNum]);

     cm_setInfowindow(infowindow);
   }
   ```
3. replace the function `cm_createMarker` with:

   ```
   function cm_createMarker(map, latlng, title, html, rank) {

     var iconImageUrl;
     var iconImageOverUrl;
     var iconImageOutUrl;

     if(rank > 0 && rank < 100) {
       iconImageOutUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
           "markers/" + param_iconType + "/marker" + rank + ".png";
       iconImageOverUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
           "markers/" + param_iconOverType + "/marker" + rank + ".png";
       iconImageUrl = iconImageOutUrl;
     } else { 
       iconImageOutUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
           "markers/" + param_iconType + "/blank.png";
       iconImageOverUrl = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" +
           "markers/" + param_iconOverType + "/blank.png";
       iconImageUrl = iconImageOutUrl;
     }

     var markerOptions = {
       title: title,
       icon: iconImageUrl,
       map:map,
       position:latlng
     }

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
       cm_setInfowindow(infowindow);
       marker.setIcon(iconImageOutUrl);
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
       marker.setIcon(iconImageOverUrl);
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
       marker.setIcon(iconImageOutUrl);
     });

     return marker;
   }
   ```

Not related to the issue:

Remove this line:

```
 setTimeout('cm_load()', 500);
```

and define `cm_load` as callback for the API:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=cm_load">
</script>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks so much! I thought that maybe deprecation was the problem but was having a hard time figuring out how to update the code.  Perfect!